# How to call a function in a function

Tags: php, function, class

How can I call a function in a function within a class?

My code looks like this (examplified)

```
    class Test
{

    echo $this->unique();

    public function unique($unique = FALSE)
    {
        function random()
        {
            return 1;
        }

        while($unique === FALSE)
        {
            return $this->random();
            $unique = TRUE;
        }
    }

}
```

But I get the following error:
**Call to undefined method Test::random()**

Comment: You're declaring the function inside another function, so you just call it in local scope like `random()`, `$this->random()` would only be used if the function belongs to the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `$this->random();`, it's just `random()`.

Your nested function is not a method of the `Test` class, it's just a function, local to the method in which you declared it.

---

Note that your code appears to have some pretty serious flaws.

This code will not work; the while loop will *only* ever execute once, and it will only execute the `return` statement. Program flow can never reach the `$unique = TRUE` line.

```
    while($unique === FALSE)
    {
        return $this->random();
        $unique = TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: @JohnSmith Note that you have written some pretty serious bugs into your code; see my update

Answer (score 0):

Just use random();

```
class Test
{

    echo $this->unique();

    public function random()
    {
        return 1;
    }


    public function unique($unique = FALSE)
    {

        while($unique === FALSE)
        {
            return random();
            $unique = TRUE;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

This is an Example Code:

This is you current main function:

```
function parentFuntion()
{
  childFuntion();
}
```

And this is the function which you are trying to call from your main function

```
function childFuntion()
{

}
```